# TSLint marks body-parser as deprecated

Tags: typescript, tslint, body-parser

I have the Typescript code below:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

...
const app: express.Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In VSCode the bodyParser on the last line is marked with yellow squiggles saying that body-parser is deprecated.

In the .d.ts file I see the following:

```
/** @deprecated */
declare function bodyParser(
    options?: bodyParser.OptionsJson & bodyParser.OptionsText & bodyParser.OptionsUrlencoded,
): NextHandleFunction;

declare namespace bodyParser {
...
    function json(options?: OptionsJson): NextHandleFunction;
```

Why is the linter complaining about the body-parser function while I do not use it as a function in my code? Am I missing something in a tsconfig.json file to prevent this? Compiling doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Is this Express?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've added some more code lines to make that clear.

Comment: IIRC, Express.js has the function of body-parser built in since V4.16 or something like that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

BodyParse is built into Express js

So now you don't have to install body-parser, do this instead.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I had seen this before but didn't pay enough attention because I didn't realise it also meant that I shouldn't use the original body-parser. Still I don't understand the lint warning because the deprecation annotation is only before the function that I'm not using.

Comment: You are welcome :) , You could accept the answer so people know its a working solution

Comment: if you are looking for some popcorn eating material: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/428

Answer (score 8):

## Do not use body-parser anymore

Since Express 4.16+ the body parsing functionality has become **builtin** with express

So, you can simply do

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

using express directly, without having to install body-parser.

uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**Then you can access the POST data, using `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or if body comes as string,

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```

Comment: what is app and express values here?

Comment: @sam It's from the library. `const express = require("express");` and `const app = express();`